# Plot attribute missing from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am installing matplotlib with `pip install matplotlib`  on a juypter hub instance.

When I go to import I get the following error:

> ----> 4 import matplotlib.plot as plt
> 5 import seaborn as sns
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.plot'

I couldn’t find anything on here. I have tried to manually install via command line on Linux from git but that didn’t seem to work either. Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: You probably meant `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper command is `import matplotlib.pyplot`. If everything is correctly installed it shoud work.